# Trying to understand Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I'm having some trouble understanding when to "go back" while using Dijkstra's algorithm. For example:

[image]

When I tried to solve this, all went fine until I arrived at E (I did ABE). 
Going from E, G = [12+9 = 21], C = [12+10 = 22], H remains unchanged because [12+10 = 22] > 6.

What I'd do next is choose G and then do this again and choose C and then J, but that gives me a distance of 28. In these solutions at some point my professor went back after getting to G and went to C... or something. Help me understand this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going from $A$->$B$->$E$ is already false.
First, starting at $A$, you put $(B,5)$, $(H,6)$ and $(F,10)$ in your queue.

As B has a smaller distance, you next look at B and all its outgoing distances. Thus now you put $(E,12)$ and $(D,13)$ inside.

HOWEVER, as your next step you dont look at $E$, but at $H$, because it is your lowest distance in your queue.

Doing it like this guarantees you that you always look at a new node when the distance from start to it is as low as possible. Thus, when you reach your target, you know that this is the optimal path.

Comment: By "queue" you mean the vertices I haven't "visited" yet?

Comment: Your greedy algorithm doesn't always work. Suppose we have four nodes $A,B,C,D,$ with paths $A\to B$ (1 unit), $A\to C$ (2 units), $B\to D$ (3 units), and $C\to D$ (1 unit), and we want the shortest path from $A$ to $D$. Then your algorithm finds the (non-optimal) path $A\to B\to D$ and halts.

Comment: @TonyK What would be a better algorithm?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire Yes excatly. You start with an empy queue, fill them up with neighbors of $A$ and each time you visit a node, add all new neighbors/update old neighbors and then remove the node itself from the queue.

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire: umm...Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: @TonyK that's what I am trying to do here...

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire: I know! But Nurator is feeding you with false information.

Comment: @TonyK I am trying to explain Dijkstra here :D I think this whole comment section is just a big misunderstanding :D

Comment: Nurator, you have to examine the nodes in increasing order of the _number of steps_ from the start, not the distance from the start. I think perhaps this is the misunderstanding. (But the optimal path might not use the minimum number of steps, so your guarantee doesn't hold.)

Comment: @TonyK I am pretty sure that this is not true. Quote from wiki: "select the unvisited node that is marked with the smallest distance from start and set it as the new "current node" " If you consider the number of steps from start, you could easily run into worse distance nodes that could be reached with a lower distance with a path through several nodes. And as your target function is the distance, I am not sure why I want to minimize the number of steps. Please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm to prove me wrong, but right now your reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: Nurator, you just have to look at my counterexample to see that your guarantee is wrong. Have you done that? Why doesn't it convince you?

Comment: @TonyK Ok I am going step by step through your example: Starting at $A$ brings $(B,1)$ and $(C,2)$ to the queue. Investigating $B$ next brings $(D,4)$ to the queue. $(C,2)$ is the next lowest one, so we put in $(D,3)$, thus removing $(D,4)$. Lastly $(D,3)$ is in our focus and because it is our target, we stop here. I always looked at the node in the queue with the lowest distance from start right now. Can it be, that the "lowest distance" you are talking about is the number of nodes you pass through, while I mean adding all numbers at the edges? I still think this is a misunderstanding :D